# How to set a DepedencyProperty by a style setter?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, styles, dependency-properties, setter

My user control have the following DP:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonAnimationColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonAnimationColor", typeof(Color), typeof(MyControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Colors.RoyalBlue, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, ThemeUpdate));

    public Color ButtonAnimationColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(ButtonAnimationColorProperty ); }
        set { SetValue(ButtonAnimationColorProperty , value); }
    }
```

This control is compiled into a dll, that I use in others solutions. It works perfect well when I set directly:

```
<ns:MyControl ButtonAnimationColor="Green" />
```

The problem occurs when I try to set this DP by using a Style Setter, like that:

```
<ns:MyControl>
    <ns:MyControl.Style>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="ButtonAnimationColor" Value="Green" />
        </Style>
    </ns:MyControl.Style>
</ns:MyControl>
```

It give me the following error:

The member "ButtoAnimationColor" is not recognized or is not acessible.

What changes I need to make in my code to be able to set the property like that?

Comment: Did you spell it correctly? Your error is `ButtonnimationColor`.

Comment: Sorry, consider the code. I will update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the target type for the style:

```
<ns:MyControl.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ns:MyControl}">
        <Setter Property="ButtonAnimationColor" Value="Green" />
    </Style>
</ns:MyControl.Style>
```

Comment: Works perfectly, only need quotes like that: TargetType="{x:Type ns:MyControl}"

Comment: Woops. Added them to the answer.